# Geopandas Line Polygon Intersection

Tags: python, intersection, shapely, geopandas

I'm trying to find where multiple lines intersect a polygon for two different geodataframes:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString
import geopandas as gpd

polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)])
line1 = LineString([(0.5, 0.5), (0.7, 0.7)])
line2 = LineString([(0.9, 0.9), (0.2, 0.6)])


poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[polygon])
line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line1, line2])
```

This is what the above geodataframes look like (one has a polygon and the other has two lines). It looks to me as if both lines intersect the polygon:

[image: Polygon and Lines]

However, the intersect output is very confusing:

```
print(line_gdf.intersects(poly_gdf))
```

> > 0 True
> >
> > 1 False

```
print(line1.intersects(polygon))
print(line2.intersects(polygon))
```

> > True
> >
> > True

Why does the `geopandas` `intersect` method give a different output to the standard `shapely` one?

I am using Python 3.5.3 and Geopandas 0.2.1 all on Anaconda.

Comment: When you say `print(line.intersects(polygon))` you're access a variable that isn't defined as far as I can see.  You've defined `line1` and `line2` earlier in the code.  I don't know why that would return True.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this as well.  It seems that you can only assign a single geometry column to a geodataframe.  I think your line_gdf data frame tries to add two geometry columns.  Check out   http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html#geodataframe

Comment: @Paul my apologies, `print(line.intersects(polygon))` was a typo. I have updated the question to refer to `line1` which is what I originally meant.

Comment: @Paul I can see from the documentation how having two geometry columns would cause an issue, but I'm not quite sure why two geometry columns would be added in the first place.

Comment: `line_gdf.info` confirms that you only have a single geometry column.  I'm stumped.  I'll follow up if I find anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When comparing geodataframes with geometry operations in Geopandas, the geometries are first matched by index. In the case where there is no matching index (because you only have a single polygon for instance) then the result will be `False`.

If it were to compare each object in the `GeoSeries` you would instead need to get back a full rectangular dataframe of boolean values, and this would likely be very inefficient.

If you do want to compare all geometries then you have two options. The first (and probably easiest) is to use the geopandas [`sjoin`](http://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins) method:

```
gpd.sjoin(line_gdf, poly_gdf, op='intersects')
```

This returns a new `GeoDataFrame` with the geometries for each object on the left dataframe repeated for each geometry they intersect in the right, with the index of the object in the right, i.e.:

```
                        geometry  index_right
0  LINESTRING (0.5 0.5, 0.7 0.7)            0
1  LINESTRING (0.9 0.9, 0.2 0.6)            0
```

The second method is to us the pandas [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method on the `GeoSeries` to return the rectangular dataframe:

```
line_gdf.geometry.apply(lambda g: poly_gdf.intersects(g))
```

Which in turn returns (with increasing inefficiency as the dataframes grow):

```
index_right     0
index_left
0            True
1            True
```

In general, unless you needed the square matrix, my advice would be to stick to the `sjoin` method.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is the following:

`print(line_gdf['geometry'].intersects(poly_gdf['geometry'].values[0]))`

> 0    True
>
> 1    True
>
> dtype: bool

where the number before True is the index of the line.
By selecting the 'geometry' column it returns Geoseries instead of GeoDataFrame which can leverage the spatial index and apply the [intersects](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects) method. At least that is how I understood it, happy to receive better explanations-